# New List Item - How can I change the order of fields in the form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I need to change the order in which some fields appear on the new list item form for one of my custom lists.  Regardless of the ordering in the view I have selected, the fields always seem to appear in the order they were created on the new item form.

Note:  I don't have infopath so can't do it in there.  Also, I'm using Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open the site with SharePoint Designer and navigate to your list
2. Open the "NewForm.aspx"
3. Move your favorite columns to the top

Best Regards from Munich

Comment: Ahh.. that got me most of the way there - newform.aspx doesn't seem to contain any fields specifically but I created a new 'New List Item' form and that does contain the markup for the field layout.  Cheers.

Comment: Check the answer below, it is far easier to use than having to deal with Sharepoint designer...

Answer (score 71):

Found the answer [elsewhere](http://sharedpointers.blogspot.com/2011/08/changing-order-of-fields-in-edit-or.html) that doesn't require SharePoint Designer:

Just a quick post in answer to a question I got yesterday:
How do you change the order of fields in edit or display forms?

1. Go to the list
2. Enter list settings (from the ribbon in 2010, from the drop downs in 2007)
3. Click Advanced settings
4. Ensure ‘allow management of content types’ is checked
5. Go back to the list settings
6. In the list of content types associated with the list, click the one you want to change the order of fields for (in lists that have been created ad hoc this is usually item or document).
7. In the bottom of the screen a link appears called ‘Column order’
8. Return to Advanced settings and deselect 'allow management of content types' to ensure the Content Type field does not appear at the top of the New Item field.

Comment: Imo this is the best solution here, editting a page in SharePoint designer should only be done if there's really no other choice.

Comment: This is good because it also reorders the columns in the list view, hupseb's answer is good because it allows you to customize the layout more fully.

Comment: Confirmed working for SharePoint 2013 on-premises as well.

Comment: This technique may not work with lookup columns which include additional fields. I have several have of these in a list. Most of them appeared in the content type column order page, but one didn't. I play around a bit and now two additional fields no longer appear. I can't see any reason why these are affected but the other lookup column additional fields continue to appear.

Answer (score 9):

From the List, click List tab on the ribbon
Click List Settings

Under Content Types header, click "Item" (It's a clickable hyperlink even though it doesn't look like it!)

[image]

Scroll to the bottom and click "Column Order"
Update Position from Top number and click Ok.

Comment: +1 `It's a clickable hyperlink even though it doesn't look like it` the actual reason why having to look this up was even needed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of @AndyLevesque answer

Comment: @JohnC Not entirely; it focuses on just the meat, and provides more information about the action required, including a helpful screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your List Settings and click 'Column Ordering' within the Columns section. Your column orders aren't set within the different views, that's only how they appear in the view itself.

Comment: I've changed the column ordering in there too but it has no effect on the new item form ordering.

Answer (score 2):

To change the order displayed in the "New Item" pop-up form, click List under List Tools - Next click on List Settings on the ribbon at the right - scroll down to the end of the columns and click on the "Column ordering" link. There is where you reorder the items that will be displayed when clicking the "New Item" icon. That takes care of the New Item pop-up. If you want to change the order displayed in your normal list on the SharePoint site, click on "Modify View" icon which is just below the List tab - scroll down and reorder the numbering to what you want to see on your screen - then scroll to bottom and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can only do this through Designer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from [Social.MSDN via TechNet](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2d1697e5-004a-4e92-8a7a-bed315489e05/how-do-i-customize-sharepoint-alerts-selection-of-fields-and-order-in-which-fields-are-displayed?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) (scroll down to answer by Michael_ICS).  It can be changed in the UI, don't have to use Sharepoint Designer.   It involves hacking the list URL to "formedt" to access a dialog box that allows you to change the order.

The post was specific to alerts but it works with list forms as well.

Answer (score 0):

Question:
It appears that my column ordering option has gone away in my main view under List Settings.  It has vanished from the section under the alphabetical list of my columns and before the Views section.  Is this because I used InfoPath to make the form fancy?

Comment: This can happen if you have Content Type management enabled (more than one content types available). If you select a specific content type, you should get the option to order columns there